# Retrieve image data format from ImageReader into BufferBytes?

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer

Below I carry my code where I saved the ByteBuffer bytes in a ByteBuffer.
Using this method I can extract image data such as size, color space, pixel size, padding, data type, etc. ?

If I go to debugging where can I find this information?

```
    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener () {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable (ImageReader reader)
                    Image imagereader = null;
                    
                        imagereader = reader.acquireLatestImage ();
                        ImagePlane plane = imagereader.getPlanes () [0];
                        ByteBuffer buffer = plane.getBuffer ();
                        byte [] bytes = new byte [buffer.capacity ()];
                        buffer.get (bytes);
                        save (bytes);
                        imagereader.close ();

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mImageFileName);
                fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mImage.close();
}
```

I would then use this to manage this information through a C ++ function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Bitmap#copyPixelsFromBuffer` ?

Comment: What are `BufferBytes`?

Comment: @pskink I tried this way but I crash.

Comment: what crash? whats the stacktrace?

Comment: @pskink Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)' on a null object reference

Comment: so your `Bitmap` is simply null - you have to create a new `Bitmap`

Comment: @pskink Does it mean that I can not copy the buffer in the bitmap?

I would like to be able to trace the data structure of the image I captured.

Comment: you cannot use `copyPixelsFromBuffer` on a null `Bitmap` object

Comment: I tried: 


try
                        {
                            bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


and Exception.detailMessage: Buffer not large enough for pixels

Comment: whats the buffer size? whats the bitmap size?

Comment: buffer.capacity = 12192768

and Bitmap:
 mBuffer = {byte[12192768]@5168} 
 mDensity = 480
 mHeight = 3024
 mIsMutable = true
 mNativePtr = 480128522016
 mNinePatchChunk = null
 mNinePatchInsets = null
 mRecycled = false
 mRequestPremultiplied = true
 mWidth = 4032

Comment: and the `Config` is? `ARGB_8888`?

Comment: Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(imagereader.getWidth(), imagereader.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);

Comment: buffer capacity is 12192768 and buffer limit is ...?

Comment: Buffer limit is identical to buffer capacity

Comment: ok and `ImageReader`'s `getImageFormat` is ... ?

Comment: ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);